# Pass variable as a parameter to a jQuery anonymous function

Tags: jquery

I want to pass a variable contained in a function to its subfunction, but it isn't working. It says the value is `undefined`.

```js
$('.search-input-text').keyup(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var i = $(this).attr('data-column');
  var v = $(this).val();
  
  $('#commandHistory').delay(200).queue(function(v, i) {
    alert(v);
    commandHistoryTable.columns(i).search(v).draw();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass parameters to jQuery's anonymous functions. The issue in your logic is because you change the scope of `v` within the `queue` handler function to be the parameter, not the value of `v` in the outer scope.

To address this you can simply rename the `v` parameter of the function to something else and use `v` defined in the parent scope:

```
$('.search-input-text').keyup(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let i = $(this).data('column');
  let v = $(this).val();
  
  $('#commandHistory').delay(200).queue(function(_, i) {
    console.log(v);
    commandHistoryTable.columns(i).search(v).draw();
  });
});
```

Also note the use of `data()` over `attr()` for reading the `data` attribute from your HTML.